# Foundation top bar: Toggle drop-down on click instead of hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation's top bar, the dropdowns are toggled on mouse hover. Is there are standard way to change this so that they toggle on click/touch instead?

Answer (score 0):

To finalize this behaviour, all I had to do is to add interaction on click so :

```
$(function(){

    $("li.has-dropdown").click(function(e){
        $('.dropdown').toggleClass('changed');
        return false;  
    });
});
```

and added a "changed" css class like this :

```
.changed {display:block !important;visibility:visible !important}
```

Taken from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/H3mqyv1_llo